# How to use Zeta Component - Mail in Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, zeta-components

I need to good Mail Library to work with mail server for send and receive mail. I search in Google and find [Zeta Mail Component](http://zetacomponents.org/documentation/trunk/Mail/tutorial.html#introduction), but I don't know to use in Laravel 5.x project. What should I do? How to add Laravel project and use it?

Answer (score 1):

1.install via composer like this 'composer require zetacomponents/mail' or by adding it inside your composer.json 
2.Inside your laravel controller you can then do this

```
    $imap = new \ezcMailImapTransport( "imap.example.com" );
```

it works for me.